# Show that this term is positive

Tags: analysis, optimization

Let f : $ R^d \rightarrow R $ a differentiable function and L- regular.

Let $ x^1 \in R^d $ et $x^t$ defined by : $ x^{t+1} = x^t - 1/ L \nabla f(x^t) $ 
How can I show that
$|f(x^{t+1}) - f(x^{t}) - \nabla f(x^{t})^T (x^{t+1} - x^{t})|$ is positive

Comment: The absolute values suggest it's at least greater than or equal to $0$. It also won't be strictly positive necessarily if, for example, $f$ were the $0$ function. Surely there must be loads more context to this problem? What is $f$? What is $x$ and $t$? Does $x^t$ refer to a power? Or is $x$ a function/sequence of $t$? You need to include a lot more information if you don't want this question to be closed.

Comment: Yeah mean non negatif